# Trigonometric identity reduction

Tags: trigonometry

I want to be able to reduce some trigonometric expressions that have powers of sine and cosine. For example, for arbitrary real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we can reduce the expression
$$
a\cos^2\theta + b\sin^2\theta + c\cos\theta\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)+c^2}\cos(2\theta+\varphi) + \frac{a+b}{2},
$$
where $\varphi$ is a number such that $\tan\varphi = \frac{c}{a-b}$. In particular, this allows me to determine the maximum and minimum value of the function on the left.

Can something similar be done to reduce the following:
$$
a\cos^3\theta + b\cos^2\theta\sin\theta + c\cos\theta\sin^2\theta + d\sin^3\theta?
$$
In particular, I'd like some way to be able to immediately determine the maximum (and minimum) value of the expression above for arbitrary $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

Comment: Try writing $\cos\theta=\frac12(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$ and $\sin\theta=\frac1{2i}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})$, expanding everything like crazy, and reassembling the pieces to a reduced form. (You can practice this procedure on the first identity to see how it goes, then try it on the expression you want.)